# Need Help regarding this IIF statement

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, syntax

I entered this iif statement and it says expression you entered is to complex can someone give me advice on how to approach this. Do you think i should split the formula.

```
IIf([MarkUpI]=100 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.22, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=101 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.22, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=200 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.22, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=201 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.22, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=300 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=400 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.05, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=500 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.03, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=600 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*22, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=100 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Non-Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.22, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=101 And [Stock/NonStock1]="Non-Stock",[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.05, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=200 And [Stock/NonStock1]=Non-Stock,[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.22, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=201 And [Stock/NonStock1]=Non-Stock,[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.05, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=300 And [Stock/NonStock1]=Non-Stock,[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=400 And [Stock/NonStock1]=Non-Stock,[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.05, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=500 And [Stock/NonStock1]=Non-Stock,[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*1.03, 
IIf([MarkUpI]=600 And [Stock/NonStock1]=Non-Stock,[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1]*22,0))))))))))))))))
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO]! Be sure to format your code so that folks can read it.  Either put 4 spaces at the beginning of each line, or click the `{}` button.

Comment: splitted for readability but it is just one big line

Comment: @iDevlop I have never used this function can you please explain it to me.

Comment: This data ought to be in a table, IMO.  Have Markup, Stock/NonStock, and MarkupRate (which is the last number in the math parts of the expression).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using `Switch()` function instead of embedded `iif`s.
You could also leave those 5 cases where the factor is 1.22 as a "Else" case

It seems you could also create a table with the different [MarkUpI] and [Stock/NonStock1] values and JOIN that table to get what you need ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears Access has a limit to the amount of nested IIFs, but in your case you can divide it into 2 main IIFs (for Stock and Non-Stock), with the others nested inside these, and remove the common calculation as follows:

```
CalcResult: [QTY1]+[UnitPrice1] *
    IIf([Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",
        IIf([MarkUpI]=100,1.22,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=101,1.22,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=200,1.22,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=201,1.22,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=300,1,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=400,1.05,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=500,1.03,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=600,22,0)))))))),
    IIf([Stock/NonStock1]="Non-Stock",
        IIf([MarkUpI]=100,1.22,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=101,1.05,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=200,1.22,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=201,1.05,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=300,1,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=400,1.05,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=500,1.03,
        IIf([MarkUpI]=600,22,0))))))))))
```

**NOTE:** I'm not saying this is the best way to do it (I also agree that a lookup table would be better) but this will get you around your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to do it all in a query, then use the Switch function like this:

```
[QTY1]+[UnitPrice1] *
IIf([Stock/NonStock1]="Stock",
Switch([MarkUpI]=100,1.22,[MarkUpI]=101,1.22,[MarkUpI]=200,1.22,[MarkUpI]=201,1.22,[MarkUpI]=300,1,[MarkUpI]=400,1.05,[MarkUpI]=500,1.03,[MarkUpI]=600,22,0),
Switch([MarkUpI]=100,1.22,[MarkUpI]=101,1.05,[MarkUpI]=200,1.22,[MarkUpI]=201,1.05,[MarkUpI]=300,1,[MarkUpI]=400,1.05,[MarkUpI]=500,1.03,[MarkUpI]=600,22,0))
```

But you really want to **use a lookup table** as the others have strongly suggested. It would be a LOT easier to change the values later and would look like this:

```
Stocked MarkupI Amt
Stock   100 1.22
Stock   101 1.22
Stock   200 1.22
Stock   201 1.22
Stock   300 1
Stock   400 1.05
Stock   500 1.03
Stock   600 22
Non-Stock   100 1.22
Non-Stock   101 1.05
Non-Stock   200 1.22
Non-Stock   201 1.05
Non-Stock   300 1
Non-Stock   400 1.05
Non-Stock   500 1.03
Non-Stock   600 22
```